# How can I align divs horizontally and yet still be responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Sorry this is stupid question but I'm developing a website for a client but I'm more of a back-end guy and know less to nothing in HTML/CSS/JS

My question is, is there anyway I can make every 2 lines in a different column maybe? yet still being responsive when viewed from a different device

JUST TO CLARIFY: 2 lines each column

this is the actual design http://prntscr.com/4ypwh1

And here's the jfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/38hhwf2f/

```css
.wrapper, .extra_wrapper {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.col2 {
 color: #363335;
}

h5 {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 color: #5b6a7f;
 font-weight: 600;
}

.fleft {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 1.4em;
    margin-right: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.img_inner {
    max-width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<img class="img_inner fleft noresize" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/110x109">
<div class="extra_wrapper">
        <div class="col2"><h5>Hello user</h5></div>
        <div class="col2"><a href="#">Something</a> 246</div>
        <div class="col2"><a href="#">Nothing</a> 0</div>
        <div class="col2"><a href="#">What</a> 4</div>
        <div class="col2"><a href="#">Placeholder</a> 0</div>
        <div class="col2"><a href="#">Watcha looking</a> 0</div>
        <div class="col2">Somewhere</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Not clear. Why all the col2? You want to put 2 (two) col2 next to each other per row?

Comment: Yes, I would like to put 2 col2's next to each other and when viewed on different devices to be in a list

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing as it's not clear to me, but I assume you mean you want two links per row and you want that it shouldn't squish together when it's on a small viewport. Changed the .extra_wrapper to a unordered list and changed col2 to li (no class).

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2gpccsbk/1/**

```
ul.extra_wrapper {list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
ul.extra_wrapper a {color:#363335;}

@media (min-width:600px) {
  ul.extra_wrapper li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
      display:inline-block;
      width:48%;
   }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="extra_wrapper">
        <li><h5>Hello user</h5></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a> 246</li>
        <li><a href="#">Nothing</a> 0</li>
        <li><a href="#">What</a> 4</li>
        <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a> 0</li>
        <li><a href="#">Watcha looking</a> 0</li>
        <li>Somewhere</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Christina, and sorry I just spend the last 12 hours coding and just want to sleep but I have to do this thing before I get paid.

Thanks a lot this is what I was looking for

Comment: Use 48% on the width of the li in the min-width instead of 40%. You have to make it just shy or you will need to format the html without any space.